# What is difference between .hpi and .jpi of Jenkins plugins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed Jenkins plugins in two ways i.e. manually keeping the `.hpi` file in Jenkins home directory, and installing from Jenkins front-end (Manage  Jenkins > Manage Plugins).

What I notice here is when I install the plugin manually (downloaded as `.hpi` file) it installed with extension `.hpi` and while installing the plugin through Jenkins front-end I notice that plugin again installed as `.jpi`.

But why? What is going on in the background? I know functionality won't change but it looks interesting to know.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Both are supposed to be identical to that extend that Jenkins is renaming `hpi` to `jpi` when you install it manually as you said.

The reason why you see both in your JENKINS_HOME is the order in which plugins are loaded when Jenkins boots up: `plugin.jpi` gets precedence over `plugin.hpi` in case both are present. This is the way the upload installation makes sure the uploaded version will override the existing one after the restart.

Comment: Is it documented anywhere about the precedence? I have a case in which there are two versions of a plugin, hpi (which is an older version), and jpi, the hpi one ended up taking precedence, thus causing issues to other dependant plugins due to incompatibility.

Comment: @Arcobaleno, I do not think it is documented, but it can be [verified in code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/89d37d8ee34524fe2abfb8f2b7d5409eba70cc5e/core/src/main/java/hudson/init/InitStrategy.java#L45-L60). Your observation feels strange to me. In general, either let Jenkins manage `plugins/` dir content by manipulating plugins through Jenkins, or - when managing the files yourself - always stick to one suffix for all the files.

Answer (score 2):

Plugins as present in `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/` should always be using the `.jpi` suffix (with the basename being the plugin identifier). Normally Jenkins will enforce this naming pattern even when [uploading a plugin manually](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/8d73038a27420fdee0f5b4f97b47229c243345e8/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/UpdateCenter.java#L1957), regardless of what filename you used for the upload, so I am not sure how you came to have a `*.hpi` file here, unless you directly copied it into this filesystem location.

Answer (score 1):

Functionally speaking, both are the same.

I found only one slight difference:

In the 2023 version: 2.411, in the case of offline plugins (compiled manually) if you paste the hpi file into `/var/jenkins_home/plugins` the plugin is not installed. I had to rename it and plugin was automatically installed at the server start:

```
RUN mv /var/jenkins_home/plugins/easy-webhook-plugin.hpi /var/jenkins_home/plugins/easy-webhook-plugin.jpi
```

So that could be another difference: hpi are not installed at the start, only jpi plugins