# How to install jenkins plugins from command line?

Tags: testing, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there any option to install jenkins plugins from command line ?

I found a command for this after a bit google search :

```
java -jar /var/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war -s http://127.0.0.1:8080/ install-plugin ${Plugin_Name}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Although answering 3 years late, I still think "not working" does not contribute to any knowledge towards the solution. Please provide the error info with inputs. This might help any seeker to know if inputs params, and error responses are matching his/her criteria.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As per the Jenkins [command line interface documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI), you need to use the **client** JAR file (not the **server** WAR file you're using), which you can obtain directly from Jenkins, e.g. via the links on http://localhost:8080/cli

Then you can run the command using this JAR:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://127.0.0.1:8080/ install-plugin <name>
```

This will download install the plugin you want, along with any of its dependencies.

Comment: If you have run jenkins from a war file then the jenkins-cli.jar will most likely have been unpacked and cached here: /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar

Comment: I didn't find it there, but it was in `/var/jenkins_home/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar`.

Comment: Thanks for this. For anyone having issues running the command and getting this error: `ERROR: anonymous is missing the Overall/Read permission` you'll need to provide the `-auth` command switch like so: `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 -auth <username>:<password> install-plugin <plugin-1> <plugin-2> ...` and, also, make sure that the `-auth <username>:<password>` portion comes before the `install-plugin` argument. In other words, the order of the arguments matters. It goes without saying that the Jenkins user you are using must have sufficient privileges.

Comment: I am using a bootstrap script in EC2 instance to use Jenkins CLI. Once I finish installing Jenkins I run 
"sudo wget http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar" to get CLI but I am receiving 503 Service not available error for a specific time. I can not use loop to wait for the service to be available. Is there any nice way to do this in EC2 Bootstrap script?

Answer (score 7):

```
import jenkins.model.* 
import java.util.logging.Logger

def logger = Logger.getLogger("") 
def installed = false 
def initialized = false

def pluginParameter="gitlab-plugin hipchat swarm" 
def plugins =pluginParameter.split() 
logger.info("" + plugins) 
def instance =Jenkins.getInstance() 
def pm = instance.getPluginManager() 
def uc =instance.getUpdateCenter() 
uc.updateAllSites()

plugins.each {   logger.info("Checking " + it)   if
(!pm.getPlugin(it)) {
    logger.info("Looking UpdateCenter for " + it)
    if (!initialized) {
      uc.updateAllSites()
      initialized = true
    }
    def plugin = uc.getPlugin(it)
    if (plugin) {
      logger.info("Installing " + it)
        plugin.deploy()
      installed = true
    }   } }

if (installed) 
   {  
      logger.info("Plugins installed, initializing a   restart!")   
       instance.save()  
       instance.doSafeRestart()
 }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `uc.updateAllSites()` more than once? Is it intentional?

Comment: what if the plugin is not successfully installed, how do you retry?

Comment: Ok I take that back. It seems to retry. But it seems that it goes into a loop of endlessly restarting. Any idea why @giorgian

Comment: I should add that I put this in the 'init.groovy.d' directory so that installation happens during the bootup. How do I install the plugins using the above and avoid going into this loop?

Comment: The loop appears because plugin.deploy() actually returns Future. Because of that jenkins restarts before installation is complete. And after next start the same thing happens. So you need to wait until the plugin is installed. Instead of plugin.deploy() it should be plugin.deploy().get() for example

Answer (score 6):

Since Sept 2019, you can also use the [Plugin Installation Manager Tool](https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-installation-manager-tool). It takes a yaml file listing the plugins, and downloads plugins to a folder of your choice. There is no need to have a running Jenkins instance. You can specify the plugin versions in the yaml file, but be aware of [JENKINS-60205](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-60205).

Get the plugin manager:

```
version=1.0.1
curl \
    -L \
    -X GET "https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-installation-manager-tool/releases/download/plugin-management-parent-pom-$version/jenkins-plugin-manager-$version.jar" \
    -o jenkins-plugin-manager-$version.jar
```

Download the plugins:

```
java -jar jenkins-plugin-manager-$version.jar \
    --plugin-download-directory pluginsFolder \
    --plugin-file plugins.yml \
    --war jenkins.war
```

The plugins are in the `pluginsFolder`.

Answer (score 2):

You will need jenkins-cli.jar file.
It can be downloaded from ${JENKINSURL}/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar

```
wget http://localhost:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar
```

To install a plugin :

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -auth ${USER}:${PASSWORD} -s ${JENKINSURL} install-plugin ${PLUGIN_NAME}
```

If you dont provide auth you will get error:

> ERROR: anonymous is missing the Overall/Read permission

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. It's really close to the accepted answer, which worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

My command:

```
jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins "snyk-security-scanner:2.12.1 file-operations:1.11 branch-api:2.5.6 pipeline-build-step:2.13 workflow-support:3.8 aws-credentials:1.28 subversion:2.13.1 github-branch-source:2.7.1 publish-over-ftp:1.15 cloudbees-folder:6.740.ve4f4ffa_dea_54"
```

And the one I used in dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root

# Install custom plugins
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins "snyk-security-scanner:2.12.1 file-operations:1.11 branch-api:2.5.6 pipeline-build-step:2.13 workflow-support:3.8 aws-credentials:1.28 subversion:2.13.1 github-branch-source:2.7.1 publish-over-ftp:1.15 cloudbees-folder:6.740.ve4f4ffa_dea_54"

# Set environment variables
# ENV <ENV_VARIABLE_1> <VALUE>
# ENV <ENV_VARIABLE_2> <VALUE>

USER jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find some straight forward command for installing plugins.
Please take a look at this link: [How to install a plugin in Jenkins manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950408/how-to-install-a-plugin-in-jenkins-manually)

But it needs to download the plugin first(*.hpi file) and run it manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is my soluction!

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/plugins.txt:/usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
    command: >
        bash -c "jenkins-plugin-cli -f /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
        && ./usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"
```

Contents of plugins.txt:

```
ant:latest
antisamy-markup-formatter:latest
build-timeout:latest
cloudbees-folder:latest
configuration-as-code:latest
credentials-binding:latest
email-ext:latest
git:latest
github-branch-source:latest
gradle:latest
ldap:latest
mailer:latest
matrix-auth:latest
pam-auth:latest
pipeline-github-lib:latest
pipeline-stage-view:latest
ssh-slaves:latest
timestamper:latest
workflow-aggregator:latest
ws-cleanup:latest
job-dsl:latest
blueocean:latest
authorize-project:latest
```