# How to install plugins in Jenkins using command line in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins in my Ubuntu OS and now I want to install its few plugns using command line.
I have got this command :-
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://127.0.0.1:8080/ install-plugin 
from this url :-
[How to install jenkins plugins from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761047/how-to-install-jenkins-plugins-from-command-line)

Problem :-
1) I don't know what are the plugins name there for Jenkins and so please provide me few basic jenkins plugins name to put in the above command or any other command to install using CLI.

Answer (score 2):

```
java -jar /path/to/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://127.0.0.1:2206/ install-plugin github-api --username admin --password password
```

Comment: refer this document --- > www.scmgalaxy.com/tutorials/complete-guide-to-use-jenkins-cli-command-line

Answer (score 0):

For jenkins 2 see in [plugin search](https://plugins.jenkins.io/) can be Mailer, LDAP