# Generating comprehensive Jenkins plugin manifest using Plugin Manager's REST API and JQ

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jq, jenkins-api

I'm trying to get a Set of installed Jenkins plugins through the API using `curl` and `jq` but can't seem to flatten nested arrays correctly. An example of the output JSON I'm fetching:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        {
            "shortName": "foo",
            "version": "6.9",
            "dependencies": [
                {
                    "shortName": "bar",
                    "version": "4.2.0"
                },
                {
                    "shortName": "baz",
                    "version": "6.6.6"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "shortName": "fah",
            "version": "4.2",
            "dependencies": [
                {
                    "shortName": "bah",
                    "version": "1.3"
                },
                {
                    "shortName": "bar",
                    "version": "2.1.0"
                },
                {
                    "shortName": "baz",
                    "version": "6.6.6"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And here's the result that I'd like to get:

```
[
    {
        "shortName": "bah",
        "version": "1.3"
    },
    {
        "shortName": "bar",
        "version": "2.1.0"
    },
    {
        "shortName": "bar",
        "version": "4.2.0"
    },
    {
        "shortName": "baz",
        "version": "6.6.6"
    },
    {
        "shortName": "fah",
        "version": "4.2"
    },
    {
        "shortName": "foo",
        "version": "6.9"
    },
]
```

I've made various attempts at using `map` and `flatten` but can't seem to preserve the parent's keys, let alone getting a comprehensive array of each plugin and its version. The payload is easy enough to get with `curl`:

```
curl -u username:token --globoff -H "${JENKINS_CRUMB}" "${JENKINS_URL}/pluginManager/api/json?tree=plugins[shortName,version,dependencies[shortName,version]]"
```

I'd like to just pipe that output straight into `jq` to transform it into the desired results. Am I able to do this within `jq` or would I need to have some sort of wrapper for these transformations like Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making this way more difficult than it needs to be. I can just get the names of the plugins from the API:

```
curl -u $USERNAME:$TOKEN --globoff -H "${JENKINS_CRUMB}" "${JENKINS_URL}/pluginManager/api/json?tree=plugins[shortName]" | jq '.plugins[] | .shortName'
```

and then [install them and their dependencies with `jenkins-cli`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34773752/1183256):

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s $JENKINS_URL install-plugin $PLUGIN
```

---

#### Update

I ended up opting for the SSH option to interact with Jenkins' API, it's cleaner and easier to use:

```
ssh.exe -l "${USER}" -p 53801 "${HOST}" list-plugins | awk '{print $1}' > plugins.txt

for line in $(cat plugins.txt)
do
    echo "Installing ${line} plugin"
    ssh.exe -l "${USER}" -p 53801 "${HOST}" install-plugin $line
done
```