# Jenkins choice parameter with different display

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I want to add a choice parameter to a Jenkins job. The list is fixed, but I want the dropbox to display custom value, and not the actual ones (analogous to name of a web page and not its URL).

In the certain case this is the path of the `pom.xml` file, however, I want to display the module name instead of the full path. An example:

```
Actual value                         | What I want to be displayed
-------------------------------------|----------------------------
full/path/to/my/modules/pom.xml      | All modules
full/path/to/my/modules/util/pom.xml | Utilities
full/path/to/my/modules/data/pom.xml | Data handling
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the [Extended Choice Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin).

To set it the way you want, under "This build is parameterized", choose Extended Choice Parameter, and set it up like this:

[image]

Note it may look a little different depending on what version of Jenkins you have but it shouldn't be too different (this screenshot was on 2.0-beta-2).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! We have an outdated version of this plugin, and seems it does not have this feature yet. Indeed, the Jenkins itself is a bit outdated, and a warning says the latest version of the extended choice plugin may not work with our Jenkins.

Answer (score 7):

With the [Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) plugin, you can set this up with a groovy map:

Set a "Active Choices Parameter" with the following groovy script:

```
return['full/path/to/my/modules/pom.xml' : 'All modules',
'full/path/to/my/modules/util/pom.xml' : 'Utilities',
'full/path/to/my/modules/data/pom.xml' : 'Data handling']
```

[image]

The "value" of the map will be displayed in the build parameters choices:
[image]

And "key" of the map will be set in the variable:

```
> echo "$URL"
full/path/to/my/modules/pom.xml
```

Comment: How can we do it for only one parameter only?

Comment: It works with a single element in the list: return['full/path/to/my/modules/pom.xml' : 'All modules']

Comment: I get groovy error as I dont want the other parameters display names to be changed.
I want something like this 
return['full/path/to/my/modules/pom.xml' : 'All modules',
'full/path/to/my/modules/util/pom.xml' ,
'full/path/to/my/modules/data/pom.xml']

Comment: return['full/path/to/my/modules/pom.xml' : 'All modules', 'full/path/to/my/modules/util/pom.xml' : 'full/path/to/my/modules/util/pom.xml', 'full/path/to/my/modules/data/pom.xml' : 'full/path/to/my/modules/data/pom.xml'] should work.

Comment: I know this way but it will be a lengthy one.

Answer (score 0):

I found it painful that there were no easy solution to this problem for so many years, like writing a display|value line with the choice plugin, so I finally wrote my own plugin: https://github.com/Avalancs/ChoiceWithDisplay
You can get the .hpi file from the release tab, and if you don't know how to install .hpi files check this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19588907/7216760