# Jenkins "Build Pipeline Plugin" plug-in installation fails due to missing jQuery plug-in

Tags: jenkins

Trying to install "Build Pipeline Plugin v1.5.6" fails due to:

> hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from
>   http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/jquery/1.11.2-0/jquery.hpi
>   (redirected to:
>   http://ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp/software/jenkins/plugins/jquery/1.11.2-0/jquery.hpi)
>     at
>   hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1172)
>     at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1678)
>     at
>   hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1876)
>     at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1652)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Inconsistent file length: expected 3003464 but
>   only got 872533   at
>   hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1155)
>     ... 7 more

The jQuery plug-in is nowhere to be found as part of the plug-in installation...

Googling for a workaround did not give fruitful results. Maybe the Jenkins community knows how to workaround this?

Comment: That looks like a temporary network problem. Jenkins seems to get itself into a bad way when that happens during plugin installation. When that happens, you can restart Jenkins and retry the installation, or do as you did, and upload the HPI (and then restart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like downloading the plug-in's .hpi file from the [FTP site](http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/jquery/1.11.2-0/jquery.hpi) and [uploading it via the Jenkins UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950408/how-to-install-a-plugin-in-jenkins-manually) followed by restarting Jenkins resolved the issue...

It is unclear why the plug-in installation fails otherwise.

Comment: This suggestion actually solved my issue as well, but later on i figured out that the problem was in accessing the FTP site of jenkins. when i switched to my 4G hotspot everything worked fine

Comment: Would you believe it, I retried to install the plugins about 5 times, and on the 5th retry it worked. I have wired Gigabit symmetrical uncontested fiber, so its not my network.  Nothing changed between not installing and installing (except about 10 minutes passed). So if it fails, keep retrying.