# How to install jenkins offline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-plugin

I could successfully install the jenkins online over my laptop. But while trying to install the jenkins offline (on my office workstation which cannot be connected to internet) the hell breaks loose.
After running the jenkins.war over command line although the jenkins was successfully installed yet some of the plugins were missing.I managed to get some help from the post [How to install a plugin in Jenkins manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950408/how-to-install-a-plugin-in-jenkins-manually/44881080#44881080)

But then each of the plugins have to be individually downloaded and then copied over to my offline machine. So I had a trick.
I copied all the folders under `.jenkins directory` (in my online installation machine) and then copied them to my offline machine. Whoa! 
It worked!
But I still get one single error:

```
Maven Integration Plugin V2.16 .javadoc 1.0 is missing. To fix, install v1.0 or later
```

So is there a way/website/pdf/repository which is a one stop solution/steps to smoothly install (read has all the required dependencies as a zip) Jenkins in offline mode. *(If not, to the creators of Jenkins: Would it be a good idea to have one?)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also searching for an easy way to manage the dependencies between the plugins but as far as I know there is **no official tool** for that.

Either you have a **.zip file with all the plugins** which you prepare one time or you fix the errors manually.

For your problem it should be enough to install the following .hpi file: https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/javadoc.hpi (*javadoc* has no dependencies to other plugins)

Comment: This is basically what [the docs](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Offline+Jenkins+Installation) are saying. There are scripts that help with detecting plugin dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the .hpi version of plugins required and paste them in plugins folder at jenkins_home and then restart the jenkins,then you can able to use those plugins.