# Is it possible to start Jenkins without any plugin?

Tags: jenkins, offline

I must install Jenkins on a machine (a NonStop server) which has no access to the Internet. I read in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44903167/399174) that it is possible to download the .hpi files and to put them in the right directory, hoping to catch all dependencies, but at the moment the installation hangs after unblocking Jenkins, probably because it tries to access the Internet. Is there a way to force a boot without plugins? 
(By the way, NonStop servers put Jenkins under Tomcat, if this can be of any importance)

**UPDATE** After a long and fruitless work, we eventually found out that there is a bug in the NonStop implementation of servlets which hogs the machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install jenkins offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903167/how-to-install-jenkins-offline)

Comment: which I explicitly referred in my post. I read that post, but it seems that base Jenkins already started: from them, adding plugins is easy, even if not always straightforward.

Comment: retracted the vote. What's your OS. In this example it seems straight forward to install jenkins without internet connection on a RHEL: http://java-x.blogspot.de/2017/10/jenkins-offline-install-on-red-hat.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During setup of a Jenkins server, I have copied many files from other Jenkins server, including all plugins hpi files to a JENKINS_HOME/plugins folder. I used [ThinBackup](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/thinBackup) to create an archive and copied the files from it. The copying was done without using the ThinBackup restore option. The Jenkins server started successfully.
Do not forget to stop the Jenkins server before you copy the files. After you copy them you could start the Jenkins master.

I have a vague memory that I saw installed-plugins.xml file or a file with similar name in JENKINS_HOME folder. It contains a list of installed plugins. I suppose that there can be a mismatch between this file and the plugins that you try to install. Try to copy that file, as well as any plugins hpi files from a machine with internet connection to your new offline server.

You can disable plugin if you rename it in specific way (JENKINS_HOME/plugins/PLUGIN_NAME.hpi.disabled). Source [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/).