# Problem with jenkins-plugins don`t installed.Error with mirror

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I dont know why,but jenkins don`t installed plugins.

Problem:

**java.net.UnknownHostException: ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de**

Comment: Does it work if you [install the plugin manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950408/how-to-install-a-plugin-in-jenkins-manually)?

Comment: I install the plugin manually,but dependecies in plugin not installed.OS-Windows 11